# Is there a way to check reactions?

Tags: software

I'm very new to organic chemistry. 
I would like to practise simple reactions (HX + Alkenes, X2 with Alkenes and so on) with examples i create myself. Is there a way to check if my products are correct?

I have access to Chemdraw and ChemSketch, however I don't know how and if these tools can be used to do that, i.e. draw a reaction , or two educts and let them show the product.

Is there any software available which can do that?

Comment: I don't think so. There are a lot of introductory OC books with exercises.

Comment: Not really exactly what you're looking for, but if you have access you can look up a reaction up on SciFinder with its drawing functionality. If the products are too simple you might just find that people will buy it as starting material from a supplier, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In August 2018 IBM [launched](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/research/2018/08/neural-networks-organic-chemistry/) a free cloud service called [IBM RXN](https://rxn.res.ibm.com/). This neural network is quite young, but it is constantly being trained, and the prediction should get better over time. I haven't used it all that extensively, but it seems it works quite adequately for simple reactions, including the OP's case. For example:

[image]

They also published a great paper [1] which describes on which base their AI operates.

#### References

1. Schwaller, P.; Gaudin, T.; Lányi, D.; Bekas, C.; Laino, T. “Found in Translation”: Predicting Outcomes of Complex Organic Chemistry Reactions Using Neural Sequence-to-Sequence Models. *Chemical Science* **2018**, 9 (28), 6091–6098. https://doi.org/10.1039/C8SC02339E.
   ([Open Access](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/2018/sc/c8sc02339e]))